# In thermal equilibrium, why isn't $dH =0$?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

I was determining the equilibrium temperature $T_m$ of two systems with the same number of particles $N$ and the same volume $V$ with entropy $H(E,V,N)=(EVN)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ connected by a heat bridge (which doesn't contribute to the total entropy of the system). Initially they have temperatures $T_1,T_2$ I did it by setting $$\Delta E = \int_{T_1} ^{T_m}dT \ \frac {\partial E}{\partial T} = -\int_{T_2} ^{T_m}dT \ \frac {\partial E}{\partial T}$$ and solving for $T_m$. This should be correct? Now to my question: Shouldn't when thermal equilibrium has been reached the entropy be stationary, i.e. $dH=0$? But for example if I calculate $\frac{\partial H}{\partial T}$ and set it to zero I get $$\frac{1}{6\sqrt{T}}\sqrt{VN}=0,$$
which would imply that either $V$ or $N$ is zero, which can't be. How would finding an extremum to the entropy work here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is that the change in entropy of a single one of these bodies is not zero in isolation. The sum of both entropies is the one that's stationary.

$$S=S_1+S_2=k(E_1V_1N_1)^{1/3}+k(E_2V_2N_2)^{1/3}$$

So you then need to differentiate w.r.t. one of $T_1$ or $T_2$ under the constraint that $E=E_1+E_2$ is constant. Setting this to zero will yield $T_1=T_2$